# How can I generate the POST array as a clientside / JavaScript object before sending to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a mixed form of text inputs and textareas. I'm curious if I can do some local parsing before sending it to the server.  Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Example form:

```
<form>
    <div class="levelone">
        <input type="text" name="input-one">
        <input type="text" name="input-two">
        <input type="text" name="input-three">
    </div>
    <div class="levelone">
        <div class="leveltwo">
            <input type="text" name="input-arr[]">
            <input type="text" name="input-arr[]">
            <input type="text" name="input-arr[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="levelone">
        <textarea name="input-textarea">Submit</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="levelone">
        <button type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there an efficient way to get all of these inputs and textareas into a single javascript object without building it one at a time?  I'm looking for something roughly the same order and structure as what is returned server side in a POST array.

Comment: `serializeArray()` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gcW8h/**

Answer (score 1):

The structure sent to the server is a string containing the data serialized using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data format. Converting a form into that format is what the [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method does.

```
var string_www_form_urlencoded = jQuery('form').serialize();
```